# How do I find if an android device has audio cabilities?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm working on an app which is designed to run on any android device - so not just phones, but absolutely anything which uses android.

I can easily determine if it has video/camera capabilities in code, but cannot see anything similar that allows me to check for playback/record audio.

Without setting things in the manifest, is there a simple way to check is something can play and/or record?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class to check for most hardware features.
For example:

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
    // Do camera stuff
}

if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE)) {
    // Do audio stuff
}
```